# merging tweets by date

Tags: r, text-mining, string-concatenation

I hope this is not to basic a question,
I have a dataframe of tweets (in R).
My aim is to calculate the sentiment by date.

I would be so grateful if anyone would advise me,
how to concatenate tweets `tweet$text` by date, where 
each observation becomes a string of merged tweets/text

For example, if I had:

```
Created_Date       Tweet

2014-01-04         "the iphone is magnificent"

2014-01-04         "the iphone's screen is poor"

2014-01-04         "I will always use Apple products"

2014-01-03         "iphone is overpriced, but I love it"

2014-01-03         "Siri is very sluggish"

2014-01-03         "iphone's maps app is poor compared to Android"
```

I would like a loop/function to merge the tweets by Created_Date
resulting in something like this

```
Created_Date       Tweet

2014-01-04         "the iphone is magnificent", "the iphone's screen is poor",              "I will always use Apple products"

2014-01-03         "iphone is overpriced, but I love it", "Siri is very sluggish", "iphone's maps app is poor compared to Android"
```

Here are my data

```
 dat <-   structure(list(Created_Date = structure(c(1388793600, 1388793600, 
    1388793600, 1388707200, 1388707200, 1388707200), class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), Tweet = c("the iphone is magnificent", 
    "the iphone's screen is poor", "I will always use Apple products", 
    "iphone is overpriced, but I love it", "Siri is very sluggish", 
    "iphone's maps app is poor compared to Android")), .Names = c("Created_Date", 
    "Tweet"), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
    -6L))
```

Comment: Please provide some [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) of what you want to do, this way we will better understand your problem and be able to lend you more help.

Answer (score 1):

## An example using data.table

```
setDT(ta)
# first we aggregate the data, by applying the function paste, we get 6 rows
ta[,cTweet:=paste(Tweet,collapse=","),by=Created_Date]
# I'm removing the Tweet column
ta1<-ta[,.(cTweet,Created_Date)]
# using a key on the table and unique() I only extract unique values
setkey(ta1,Created_Date)
unique(ta1)
   Created_Date                                                                                                  cTweet
1:   2014-01-03 iphone is overpriced, but I love it,Siri is very sluggish,iphone's maps app is poor compared to Android
2:   2014-01-04                  the iphone is magnificent,the iphone's screen is poor,I will always use Apple products
```

## An example using dplyr (tidyverse)

```
library(tidyverse)
# this approach first use the group_by function to group by date, 
# pipes `%>%` are used to pass from one data to the next with a 
# transformation at each step.

ta %>%
      group_by(Created_Date) %>%
      summarise(cTweet = paste(Tweet, collapse = ","))

# A tibble: 2 x 2
  Created_Date                                                                                                  cTweet
        <dttm>                                                                                                   <chr>
1   2014-01-03 iphone is overpriced, but I love it,Siri is very sluggish,iphone's maps app is poor compared to Android
2   2014-01-04                  the iphone is magnificent,the iphone's screen is poor,I will always use Apple products
```

## An example using base R

```
aggregate(ta$Tweet,by=list(ta$Created_Date),FUN=function(X)paste(X, collapse = ","))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a simple implementation using loops. Probably not the fastest solution imaginable, but easy to understand.

```
# construction of a sample data.frame
text = c("Some random text.", 
         "Yet another line.",
         "Will this ever stop.",
         "This may be the last one.",
         "It was not the last.")
date = c("9-11-2017",
         "11-11-2017",
         "10-11-2017",
         "11-11-2017",
         "10-11-2017")
tweet = data.frame(text, date)

# array with dates in the data.frame
dates = levels(tweet$date)

# initialise results with empty strings
resultString = rep.int("", length(dates)) 

for(i in 1:length(dates)) # loop over different dates
{
    for(j in 1:length(tweet$text)) # loop over tweets
    {
        if (tweet$date[j] == dates[i]) # concatenate to resultString if dates match
        {
            resultString[i] = paste0(resultString[i], tweet$text[j])
        }
    }
}

# combine concatenated strings with dates in new data.frame
result = data.frame(date=dates, tweetsByDate=resultString)
result

# output:
# date                               tweetsByDate
# 1 10-11-2017   Will this ever stop.It was not the last.
# 2 11-11-2017 Yet another line.This may be the last one.
# 3  9-11-2017                          Some random text.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the *corpus* library, then you can use the `group` argument to `term_counts` or `term_matrix` to aggregate (sum) by date.

In your case, if you are interested in counting the number of positive, negative, and neutral words, you can first create a "stemmer" that maps  words to these categories:

```
library(corpus)
# map terms in the AFINN dictionary to Positive/Negative; others to Neutral
stem_sent <- new_stemmer(sentiment_afinn$term,
                         ifelse(sentiment_afinn$score > 0, "Positive", "Negative"),
                         default = "Neutral")
```

Then, you can use this as a stemmer and get the counts by group:

```
term_counts(dat$Tweet, group = dat$Created_Date, stemmer = stem_sent)
##   group      term     count
## 1 2014-01-03 Negative     2 
## 2 2014-01-04 Negative     1
## 3 2014-01-03 Neutral     17
## 4 2014-01-04 Neutral     14
## 5 2014-01-03 Positive     1
```

Or get a matrix of counts:

```
term_matrix(dat$Tweet, group = dat$Created_Date, stemmer = stem_sent)
## 2 x 3 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
##            Negative Neutral Positive
## 2014-01-03        2      17        1
## 2014-01-04        1      14        .
```

Comment: Hi Patrick, Thank you so much for taking the time to help with my query. That is exactly what I am trying to do. I have extracted 'a lot' of posts from a number of newsGroups from one country, and am trying to group them first by newsGroup, and then aggregate. The reason I do this is I wish to examine the sentiment around events (elections). I wanted to use syuzhet, to get the emotional nuance.

Comment: Patrick. I just read another response of yours to someone else showing how you created a loop to deal with 'stopwords'  by instance. That will be a huge help as I go through a couple of million posts. Thank U vm